# How to use a two pair cable for internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, cable

Sorry if this question has been asked a lot but I cannot seem to find anything which specificly answers what I need.

I have cable ( 2 Pair Cable ) which is Orange, Blue, Orange White, Blue and white. I've done research and to be honest I dont know what type of cable this is. The cable says 2 Pair Telephone cable, but I believe it may be Cat 3.

This is wired from my downstairs, up two floors into my loft where I have a trouble with WIFI.

Is it possible to use this Cable for ethernet ? enter image description here

Comment: If the cable says "2 pair telephone cable", why do you believe it may be Cat.3? Cat.3 (or any other cable type with known specifications) is usually labeled as such. In any case, even it it was Cat.3, it can only reliably carry 10Mbps Ethernet. By the way, there is no image.

Comment: Because when I I Google CAT3 it's identical to my cable. I'm pretty confused tbh. Do you reckon it is possible to get internet through these cables ?

Answer (score 1):

Two pair of Cat3 meets the requirements for 10Mbps Ethernet at up to 100 meters. It *might* work for shorter runs of 100Mbps Ethernet, but the 100Mbps standard was really designed for two pairs of higher quality Cat5. So you might get lucky and be able to do 100Mbps Ethernet over that even though it's out of spec.

It will not work for gigabit Ethernet. Gigabit Ethernet requires 4 pair (8 conductors) of Cat5, preferably Cat5e.

<strike>Wire both ends according to 568a or 568b (pick one of those standards and wire both ends according to the standard you picked). Since you don't have the brown or green pairs, just leave those out. But follow the rules for which conductors from the blue and orange pairs go to which pins on the RJ-45 (8P8C) connector.</strike>  Oops, I wasn't thinking when I wrote that. You need one pair to 1&2, and the other pair to 3&6. You can't follow 568a or b for this because both of those standards put the blue pair on the center pins (4&5).

Comment: I have wired the cables into Pin: 1,2,3,6. I have tested it and the cables are live and run though from the base to upstairs. I have crimped them correctly too but at the end there is no internet connection when the cable downstairs is connected directly into my router.

Comment: Just as a double-check, look at one end and tell me which colors you wired to which pins. Then look at the other end and tell me which colors you wired to which pins. Post links to sharp well-lit close up photos if you can. If you have a split pair or a rolled pair, it could cause the cable to not work. Disable auto-negotiation and force 10Mbps operation on both ends of the link and see if that works. Then keep autonegotiation off and force 100Mbps operation on both ends of the link, and see if that works.

Comment: Sure I will get some pics over to you. How do you disable auto negotiation? Never done that before  if you could just tell me a programme to use etc thanks so much for your help btw.

Comment: How to disable autonegotiation varies from device to device, and OS to OS. You have to poke around in the Ethernet interface settings of the management UI of your own devices to figure out how to do it on your products.